# Is there a way to bring back a dead question?

Tags: discussion

There's a question you see that you know is good and deserves to be answered, but has not been so yet. Furthermore, the most that has happened on it is some people commenting. People haven't voted to close it, there are no votes for it; really, nothing has happened on it. Is there a way to bring it back to the attention of the MSE without offering bounty? Perhaps re-asking it?

Comment: If it only mostly dead you can try Miracle Max. But unless it's for the cause of True Love or to ruin Prince Humperdinck's day, I don't think he'll do it.

Comment: I just want to point out that adding a bounty can have a massive effect. I was searching through older problems and when I found [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296522/let-p-1-p-2-dots-p-n-be-polynomials-of-k-variables-x-1-dots-x-k-and-p), it had 3 upvotes, no answers and had been inactive for 6 months. Adding a bounty (of 100) made a huge difference - it now has 21 upvotes and has found an answer. (I also first edited it to correct a couple very minor typos, which already brought some attention and a couple upvotes, but not nearly what it eventually garnered)

Comment: The "poor man's" alternative to offering a bounty is to edit the Question.  I assume you already up-voted the Question.  As you read through the Comments, perhaps you found clarifications by the OP that ought to be added to the body text, or perhaps a mere tweaking of the title is in order.

Comment: @hardmath Assuming you have significant edits to make (and the question is objectively made better by these edits), why not. I once saw someone edit one of their questions 20+ times every 2-3 days just to add and then remove the same tag over and over again...! Obviously, don't do that.

Comment: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question) Some [related questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478) might be of interest, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There aren't really any good ways to do this outside of placing a bounty. Indeed, the bounty is here exactly to fill this need of drawing more attention to questions that haven't received enough. Even placing a bounty of 50 reputation is likely to bring considerably more attention to the question.

One other thing you might be able to do is to look over the question and make sure it's well-written and generally of good quality. Making it very clear is more likely to attract an answer. This is especially true if you've received any feedback in comments regarding this.

Definitely don't re-ask a question. The platform really doesn't work in a way that would support it - it would likely be closed as a duplicate (and if it weren't, it *should* be closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 4):

If you are wondering about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600834), just have some patience. You asked it yesterday.

I put a +50 bounty on the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881709/how-to-find-f-and-g-if-f-circ-g-and-g-circ-f-are-given) you linked in your question, since it is quite interesting. Hopefully this will also shed some light on your question

The difficulty with your question is that it is based on a false permisse, namely that you can take inverses of an unknown function which is not true in general.